# Override ParsePrimitive in ServiceStack.Text

Tags: servicestack

Does anyone know how to override the ParsePrimitive method in DeserializeType?

Basically I have a of Dictionary<string,object> and whenever a number gets parsed in I want it to always be a decimal. Currently it gets taken down to the smallest numeric type it thinks the number will fit into.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Added TryToParseNumericType but defaults to decimal

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/pull/347